# Setting Spatial Reference for Geometry Bag using ArcObjects and VBA?

Tags: arcobjects, geometry, vba

Within the ESRI SDK resources there is an example of combining polygons by use of a geometry bag. The following code appears:

```
    'Define the spatial reference of the bag before adding geometries to it.
    geometryBag.SpatialReference = geoDataset.SpatialReference
```

That makes sense, based on some of the other documentation surrounding geometry bags, but when I tried it myself, I got a compile error saying that the method didn't exist. After looking at the geometry object model diagram, it appears as if the spatial reference property of a geometry bag is read-only... so what gives?

Comment: If this really is VBA, don't you need to use "set"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the geometry bag to an [IGeometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001rm000000) first, then try setting its [SpatialReference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/SpatialReference_Property/002m0000020w000000/) property.

The behavior you describe is weird, though, since IGeometryBag descends directly from IGeometry. Are you sure you are trying to set the spatial reference on the correct interface?